# nested foreach loop for menu navigation php

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have the following code in my opencart

```
<table class="cat_lists">
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($categories as $key=>$category) { ?>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $key%2; ?>
                                <div class="c_menus">
                                    <h5><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h5>
                                    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
                                                <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
                                                <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
                                                    <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
                                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Actually the UI of the menu should look like the below image[image]

But my loop throughs the output as

[image]

How can i modify the loop to get the desired result.

**Edit-1**

Here is the html which should be converted to dynamic

```
<td>
                        <div class="c_menus">
                            <h5>Necklace</h5>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Beaded Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Long Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Pendant Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Statement Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Statement Necklaces</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="c_menus">
                            <h5>Rings</h5>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Beaded Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Long Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Pendant Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Statement Necklaces</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="c_menus">
                            <h5>Necklace</h5>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Beaded Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Long Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Pendant Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Statement Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Statement Necklaces</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="c_menus">
                            <h5>Rings</h5>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Beaded Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Long Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Pendant Necklaces</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Statement Necklaces</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
<?php echo $key%2; ?>
```

That will remove the `0` and `1` at top of your menu's.

Comment: That line is for test purpose

Comment: Ill paste my html how it should look like

Comment: Then, my friend, your output is right to me. You only need to change your css if you want to get `Earrings` to a new line. If any other problems, please include your input too.